# How to check if any one of the variable is greater than 0

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript

How can I check if any of the variables is greater than 0 from given variable in Typescript?

How can I rewrite below code so that it's more elegant/concise?

```
checkIfNonZero():boolean{
  const a=0;
  const b=1;
  const c=0;
  const d=0;
  //Regular way would be as below. 
  //How can this use some library instead of doing comparison for each variable
  if(a>0 || b>0 || c>0 || d>0){
   return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine the variables into an array and then run [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on it:

`return [a, b, c, d].some(item => item > 0)`

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the `&&` operator with the `ternary operator` like this:

```
(a && b && c && d > 0) ? true : false // will return true if all integers are more than 0
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/6bk1bs0w/

---

OR you can assign the variables to an array and use [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) like this:

```
let x = [a, b, c, d]

x.every(i => i > 0) // will return true if all integers are more than 0
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/6bk1bs0w/1/

---

OR to make the above even shorter, you can directly place the values in an array and use `every` on the array directly like this:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0].every(i => i > 0); // will return false since all integers are not more than 0
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/6bk1bs0w/3/

---

OR you can make a reusable function once and run it multiple times with just one line like this:

```
function moreThanOne(...args){
   // Insert any of the above approaches here but reference the variables/array with the word 'arg'
}

moreThanOne(3,1,2,0); // will return false as well as alert false

moreThanOne(3,1,2,4); // will return true as well as alert true
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/6bk1bs0w/2/